# Is there any known issues with using linked servers between 64bit sqlserver2005 and 32bit sql2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I seem to have problem getting linked servers working to query between database/servers running sql2000 32bit and 64bit sql2005. Is this a known bug? If so, is there a workaround, or fix?

Comment: Define working please. Have you successfully setup a Linked Server? Are you receiving a particular error message?

Comment: Is it just me, or is ServerFault.com (still) in closed beta?

Comment: was still in closed beta for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906954) issue.

> To resolve this problem, manually run the Instcat.sql script that is included with SQL Server 2000 SP3 or SP4 on the 32-bit SQL Server 2000 server or on the SQL Server 7.0 server.